# Optimization of jQuery Slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, jquery-selectors

I have the following code below I am using for a slideshow.  I would like to optimize this code and wanted to reach out to SO to try and get some assistace.  I know these selectors I am using are working but am curious if there is a more efficient way to write my galleries. I write these same situations pretty often and would like to know if others feel I am doing it right.

I am just looking for overall suggestions on the formatting, and optimization of my JS for performance as well as DRY code methodology.  Seeing how someone else would write similar code helps me for hone my own skills.

**Markup**

```
  <a id="next">next</a><a id="prev">prev</a>
    <ul id="thumbnails">
      <li><a href="/path/to/src"><img src="50x50.jpg"></a></li>
      <li><a href="/path/to/src"><img src="50x50.jpg"></a></li>
      <li><a href="/path/to/src"><img src="50x50.jpg"></a></li>
    </ul>
   <img id="main-image" src="path/to/src">
```

**JS**

```
$("#thumbnails a").click(function(e){      
  e.preventDefault();

  var $this = $(this),
      thesrc  = $this.attr('href'),
      desc = $this.attr('alt');    

  $this.addClass('current');
  $this.parent().siblings().children('a').removeClass('current');

  $("#main-image").fadeOut(400, function(){
    $('<img/>').attr('src', thesrc).load(function(){
      $("#main-image").attr('src', this.src).fadeIn(400);
      $("#caption").text(desc);
    });
  });                            
});

$("#next").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();     
   $('.current').parent().next().children('a').trigger('click');
});                                                                          

$("#prev").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();       
  $('.current').parent().prev().children('a').trigger('click');      
});
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/alapew/4/edit)*

HTML:

```
  <p>
     <a id="prev">prev</a>
     <a id="next">next</a>    
  </p>
        
   <div id="thumbnails">
      <img src="1.jpg">
      <img src="2.jpg">
      <img src="3.jpg">
   </div>
  
  <div id="main-img-container">
       <div id="main-img"></div>
  </div>
```

BASIC CSS:

```
#thumbnails img{
  height:30px;
}
div#main-img-container{
  height:200px;
  background: #eee url(loading_transparent.gif) no-repeat center center;  
}
div#main-img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background: transparent no-repeat center center;
  background-size:cover; 
}
#next, #prev{
  cursor:pointer;
  background:#eee;
  padding:4px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius:5px;
          border-radius:5px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
var $imgs = $('#thumbnails img');
var imgsN = $imgs.length;
var $main = $('#main-img');
var c = 0; // a 'current' counter

function loadImage(){
  c= c===-1? c=imgsN-1 : c%imgsN; 
  var getSrc = $imgs.eq(c).attr('src');  
  $main.stop().fadeTo(200, 0.7, function(){ // just to make loading a bit visible :)
     $('<img>').attr('src', getSrc).load(function(){
       $main.css({backgroundImage: 'url('+ this.src +')'}).fadeTo(300,1);        
     });
  });  
}
loadImage(); // first kick! :)

$imgs.click(function(){  
  c = $(this).index(); 
  loadImage();  
});

$('#prev, #next').click(function(){
  var myID = this.id=='next' ? c++ : c--;
  loadImage();
});
```

Comment: Thank you roXon this is exactly what I was looking for and it makes perfect sense.  Just one other question. For sake of the global namespace how do you recommend handling the global variables?

Comment: @jnolte I suggest you assign the type name `var`. It's not wrong to just use E.g: `varname =` instead of `var varname =` the only difference it that you might get Xscript var collisions specially if you define your vars outside a `function` scope. So just use `var varname =` unless you're trying to overwrite that variable inside the JS memory, than inside a function just use `varname = something new`

Comment: @jnolte if you like more to divide your vars with comma `,` **you're perfectly welcome to do so**. I like that too, but for some new programmers (many come here for answers) it could be an additional headache, despite the ternary operators hahah so I used var var var :)

Comment: Thanks so much. This is exactly the outcome I was looking for.  Just wanting to learn more efficient ways to write the code I am using frequently and learn a bit along the way :)

Answer (score 0):

Optimised and beautified:

```
e.preventDefault()
var $this = $(this),
    thesrc = $this.attr('href'),
    desc = $this.attr('alt')
    $this.addClass('current')
    $this.parent()
        .siblings()
        .children('a')
        .removeClass('current')
    $("#main-image").fadeOut(400, function () {
        $('<img/>').attr('src', thesrc)
            .load(function () {
            $("#main-image").attr('src', this.src)
                .fadeIn(400)
            $("#caption").text(desc)
        })
    })
    })
    $("#next").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        $('.current').parent()
            .next()
            .children('a')
            .trigger('click')
    })
    $("#prev").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        $('.current').parent()
            .prev()
            .children('a')
            .trigger('click')
    })
```

Comment: Hi @randy I am looking for more optimization.  And beautified is in the eye of the beholder.  I like single line formatting when I can.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rkSLk/ ... and click on the button **[JSLint]** The JS interpreter had a hard time. AFAIK

Comment: What happened to all the semicolons? They aren't required in javascript, but using them is good practice and helps with readability. Plus, as far as optimization, there are a few places where vanilla javascript could be used, and I'm seeing duplicate selectors.

Comment: @MrOBrian you forgot to mention : creating a **minified plugin** would also result in a *fingers pain*.

Comment: not to mention that you overlooked (and so did the OP) the missing first function line

Comment: Guess I might be learning more then he is.. sorry for the bad suggestion xD

Comment: Thanks all. I ran through jsLint.  Any other suggestions for selectors?  Also - is traversing through the dom (next(), prev(), children(), etc) more efficient than using an id / class for selection?)  It looks like more code but i feel like it would take less resources.  Just trying to learn best case.